# Manage Multiple UILocal Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have created multiple UI local Notifications , say 100. I have an array of UILocalNotifications which are scheduled as:

```
 -(void) scheduleNotification{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [self.notifications removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i< [delegate.viewController.contactList count] ; i++) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSString *name = [[delegate.viewController.contactList objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:NAME_KEY];
        NSString *birthday = [[delegate.viewController.contactList objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY];
        if (birthday) {
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
            [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
            [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
            NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:birthday];
            if (date == nil) {
                [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
                [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
                [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
                date = [formatter dateFromString:birthday];
            }
            NSCalendar *gregorianEnd = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *componentsEnd = [gregorianEnd components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

            componentsEnd.year = [[NSDate date] year];
            date = [gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd];
            self.alarmTime = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:self.mTimeInterval];
            localNotification.fireDate = _alarmTime;
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

            NSString *itemName = @"B'day Alert!!!";
            NSString *msgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Celebrate %@'s B'day",name];
            NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:itemName,MessageKey, msgName,TitleKey, nil];
            localNotification.userInfo = userDict;
            localNotification.soundName = self.soundName;
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Celebrate %@'s B'day",name];


            [self.notifications addObject:localNotification];
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented my `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate as:

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    UILocalNotification* notification;

    for (int i = 0; i< [self.settingVC.notifications count]; i++) {

        notification = [self.settingVC.notifications objectAtIndex:i];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }

}
```

Also, in `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate I have this:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *itemName = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:TitleKey];
    NSString *messageTitle = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:MessageKey];
    [self _showAlert:itemName withTitle:messageTitle];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
}
```

But the problem is that i'm not getting desired output.Any help would be appreciated. I know that at an application can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications and discards the rest. So, how I will handle those 100 or more UILocalNotification?

Comment: You may have to schedule only 64 Notifications at a time and store rest in a local application Keychain .For Every Notification Fired , retrieve the details of other notifications from keychain and schedule it.You can also perform this for every 10 notifications fired.Add Observer for every 10 Notifications fired and if there are more notifications in the queue , schedule it.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more..storing notifications in local application keychain?

Comment: Keychain is a persistent storage for iOS with added security where in you can store data.Instead of keychain , you can also use sqlite DB.Convert your UILocalNotification Object to NSDATA and store all the notification objects in Keychain or Sqlite DB.  You can then schedule your queued notifications accordint to the observer fired for every 10 notifications .Can give you code for keychain if you want.

Comment: Yes that will really help me..thnx

Comment: did you get the solution ? please help how to handle rest of the notification?