# handle multiple UILocalnotification more then 64

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

explain using code please!
Might be dublicate of this question
[Manage Multiple UILocal Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420507/manage-multiple-uilocal-notification)
But dont get answer yet?
Please focus on this question and anser
How can i manage notification more then 64?

i have local database of all `UINotification` time like following question:

[Set multiple UILocalNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579432/set-multiple-uilocalnotification)

Please answer.

Comment: when app launch first time . you can set max 64 UILocalNotification per app. so max 64 days you'll get notification. in between these days when user open app then get all remaining notification array using [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications] and then if array count is 30 then set more 34 notifications

Comment: yes because you can not set more then 64. so i just gave you logic.

Comment: ok thnks let me try for it

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to schedule more than 64 local notifications at any given time. However, there may be ways to effectively achieve what you are after.

1. If you have repeating notifications, do not manually schedule them. Instead use the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) on the `UILocalNotification` object. This property takes an `NSCalendarUnit` which can be used to set the repeat to be hourly, dayly, monthly, etc.
2. Every time the app is launched, reevaluate the scheduled `UILocalNotification` objects. Discard any that are no longer valid, and queue up as many as possible that are in the future.
3. This is the least elegant solution, but potentially the best for setting a large number of reminders for the user. However, do note before attempting this method, you are actually not going to be registering additional `UILocalNotification` objects and so your user will not be taken to the app when the notification is displayed. So with that out of the way, you could use the [calendar events and reminders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to set reminders for the user. You would want to use the [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009662) framework to handle all of the heavy lifting. The advantage with this method is that you get to schedule as many events as you want. And you could use calendar as your backing store for you notifications. So every time the app is launched you would query the `EKEventStore` using one of the predicate methods (like `- (NSArray *)eventsMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate`) to find the events you created.

Comment: evet kit not support more then 2 alerts?
Check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729933/how-to-set-5-alarm-using-event-kit
Also My condition is start date , end date, different 5 time to play alarm until end date comes?

Comment: The number of alerts is not necessarily what I was meaning for handling scheduling more than one local notification. Remember, the alerts will not be coming from your app but rather Calendar. So you are probably best creating multiple events and then setting single alerts on each event. Frankly, as I think about that option, it feels less like a good solution, just one that might work.

Comment: appreciate you answer...i tried to use event kit as above mention,but when i check calender its show the picture mention in the question.
Also if i tried to set multiple notification for et: startdate:4jan2015,end date 24jan2015,fivetime: time1 10am,11 am ,1 pm,2pm,3pm....then...set notification=days=20 rimender=5 then 20x5=100? how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are other ways to manage `UILocalNotification`.
As per apple you can set maximum 64 notifications. so to manage more then 64 notifications you can implement below logic.

First of all register first 64 Local notifications. on every app launch or didBecomeActive get remaining notifications or count using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]`. so if your count <64 then say its 30. so add new *34* notifications and now your total notification will be 64. do it every launch so it will work as per your need.

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can change the intervall by selecting `setDay`, `setMonth`, .... :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:3];

NSDate *date3Days = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components 
                                               toDate:[NSDate date] 
                                              options:0];

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray*    oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
if ( oldNotifications ) {
    [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlarm) {
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = date3Days;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = NSLocalizedString( @"Push message", @"");
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"sound.wav";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

---

If you want to set a specific time after which the `UILocalNotifications` should appear you can create a method of the above solution and loop over an array which indicates the days you like to show a notification:

```
NSArray *arrayNumbers = @[@5, @7, @14, @21, @30, @60, @90, @120];
NSDictionary *dictNotifications = 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    objectForKey:kUserDefAppStarts];

for ( NSNumber *bla in arrayNumbers ){

    NSString *strKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kUserDefAppStarts, bla];
    NSDictionary *dict = dictNotifications[strKey];
    NSString *strMessageQuestion = dict[kKeyMessage];

    [self createNotificationWithNumberOfDays:[bla integerValue]
                                  andMessage:strMessageQuestion
                                    userInfo:dict];
}
```

And here is the method you have to call

```
+ (void)createNotificationWithNumberOfDays:(int)days 
                                andMessage:(NSString *)message 
                                  userInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict{

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:days];

NSDate *dateAlert = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if( notifyAlarm ){
    [notifyAlarm setFireDate:dateAlert];
    [notifyAlarm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [notifyAlarm setSoundName:@"soundname"];
    [notifyAlarm setAlertBody:message];
    [notifyAlarm setUserInfo:dict];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

}

Comment: appreciate your code...can you create dummy sample code

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS7 You can use background app refresh to schedule local notifications too. On every refresh call you can check your database for nearest (future) notifications and schedule them same way you do in your app. We've been using this approach in one of our app and Apple seems to have no problem with it. Also note, that user can disable it, so you should convince your user, that you won't drain their battery :)

You can get more info from docs here: [What's new in iOS7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html)

and here: [application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3AperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3A)

Comment: In my case the above method is not getting called only. What might be the issue I have set 1800 interval

Answer (score 0):

Use BGTaskScheduler to schedule notifications on iOS 13.